# Visual Studio BizTalk Orchestration Design - BizTalk Mapper Tool

Tags: visual-studio-2005, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I have visual studio 2005 and BizTalk server 2006. Whenever I try to open an orchestration in VS I can only view it in the xml view. I cannot view it in design view, which is my goal. I am attempting to download the BizTalk Mapper Tool Addon for VS2005 but I cannot find it anywhere. Is there a place for me to get this addon or a work around so I can view the orchestrations in design mode?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have selected the "Developer Tools and SDK" when running the installation wizard.

[image: Developer Tools and SDK]

If you installed VS after you installed BizTalk run the installation again from *Add/Remove programs*.

Comment: I do not have BizTalk installed on my machine. Biztalk is on a remote server and VS2005 is on my local machine...so could i simply install the Developer Tools and SDK on my local machine and have it work? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can just install the Developer Tools and SDK and can develop that way.  But eventually you will want to deploy from Visual Studio to the remote server.